# Braces in Tabular after some of the rows

Tags: tables, braces

I have the following code, my problem is that the braces 'A' should be the after row A1 and B1 and the second braces should be after D1 and E1. Hope someone can help?

```
\begin{tabular}{c@{}c}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|@{}}\hline
    &$A$&$B$&$C$&$D$&$E$&$F$\\\hline
    $A1$&2&5&11&13&5&7\\\hline
    $B1$&6&8&10&10&10&10\\\hline
    $C1$&13&11&5&12&1&1\\\hline
    $D1$&6&6&5&4&2&2\\\hline
    $E1$&k&0&0&0&0&6\\\hline
    $F1$&9&3&17&0&5&\\\hline
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & 
        \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{$\underbrace{\hspace*{\dimexpr6\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth}\hphantom{012}}_{\mathcal{B}}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}&
        \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{$\underbrace{\hspace*{2\tabcolsep}\hphantom{3}}_{\mathcal{B}}$}
\end{tabular} 
& 
$\begin{array}{l}
\MyLBrace{3.5ex}{$\mathcal{A}$} \\ \\
\MyLBrace{3.5ex}{$\mathcal{A}$} \\
\end{array}$
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Please tell us how `\MyLBrace` is defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses just one `array` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{document}

$\begin{array}{|*{7}{c|}@{}c}
    \cline{1-7}
    &A&B&C&D&E&F\\ 
    \cline{1-7}
    A1&2&5&11&13&5&7& \multirow{2}{*}{$\left.\rule[1.5ex]{0pt}{1.5ex}\right\}\mathcal{A}$}\\ 
    \cline{1-7}
    B1&6&8&10&10&10&10\\ 
    \cline{1-7}
    C1&13&11&5&12&1&1&\multirow{2}{*}{$\left.\rule[1.5ex]{0pt}{1.5ex}\right\}\mathcal{A}$}\\ 
    \cline{1-7}
    D1&6&6&5&4&2&2\\ 
    \cline{1-7}
    E1&k&0&0&0&0&6\\ 
    \cline{1-7}
    F1&9&3&17&0&5&\\ 
    \cline{1-7}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} 
    & \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{\underbrace{\hspace*{\dimexpr4\tabcolsep+1\arrayrulewidth}\hphantom{123}}_{\mathcal{B}}}     
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{\underbrace{\hspace*{2\tabcolsep}\hphantom{.}}_{\mathcal{B}}}
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```